# Any way to reset Kafka StateStore during testing?

Tags: spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Spring Cloud Kafka Streams app which sets two state stores using a KStream transformer. The state stores work as expected, but when testing with EmbeddedKafka, the state stores seem to be keeping the state between successive runs of the tests. I'd like to be able to reset the states between runs but can't figure out how to do it. I was under the impression that EmbeddedKafka would remove those state stores once the tests were over, but apparently this doesn't happen.

I have verified that the values saved are the ones from the previous run of the tests and that a separate version of kafka is not currently running (only the EmbeddedKafka from the tests).

I have tried to set the @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD) and calling destroy() on the EmbeddedKafkaBroker but neither has solved the problem.

It would be ok if my tests themselves could get the state stores and reset them, but that doesn't seem possible.
I am using the 2022.0.4 version of spring cloud and version 3.6.0 of kafka-stream-test-utils.

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471226/how-to-remove-the-kafka-state-store-in-aws-msk-cluster

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the kafka state store in AWS MSK cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471226/how-to-remove-the-kafka-state-store-in-aws-msk-cluster)